# How do I keep internal state in a WebAssembly module written in Rust?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I want to do computations on a large set of data each frame of my web app. Only a subset of this will be used by JavaScript, so instead of sending the entire set of data back and forth between WebAssembly and JavaScript each frame, it would be nice if the data was maintained internally in my WebAssembly module.

In C, something like this works:

```c
#include <emscripten/emscripten.h>

int state = 0;

void EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE inc() {
    state++;
}

int EMSCRIPTEN_KEEPALIVE get() {
    return state;
}
```

Is the same thing possible in Rust? I tried doing it with a `static` like this:

```
static mut state: i32 = 0;

pub fn main() {}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn add() {
    state += 1;
}

#[no_mangle]
pub fn get() -> i32 {
    state
}
```

But it seems `static` variables cannot be mutable.

Comment: *But it seems static variables cannot be mutable.* — why do you say that? The error message **explicitly** tells you how to use them: "use of mutable static requires unsafe function or block". Now, whether that's a good idea or not is a different question...

Comment: Here's a [blog post of someone who successfully used `lazy_static!` for this purpose](https://aochagavia.github.io/blog/rocket---a-rust-game-running-on-wasm/).  Note that they needed to wrap it in a Mutex to make the compiler happy, so I don't know what the performance impact is.  And they didn't use emscripten, but rather the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` compiler target.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Francis Gagné is absolutely correct](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47722631/155423) that global variables generally make your code worse and you should avoid them.

However, for the *specific* case of WebAssembly as it is *today*, we don't have to worry about this concern:

> if you have multiple threads

We can thus choose to use mutable static variables, if we have a very good reason to do so:

```
// Only valid because we are using this in a WebAssembly
// context without threads.
static mut STATE: i32 = 0;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add() {
    unsafe { STATE += 1 };
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get() -> i32 {
    unsafe { STATE }
}
```

We can see the behavior with this NodeJS driver program:

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/state.wasm')
  .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes))
  .then(({ module, instance }) => {
    const { get, add } = instance.exports;
    console.log(get());
    add();
    add();
    console.log(get());
});
```

```
0
2
```

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster. I was not aware of the `unsafe` keyword (I'm a Rust beginner)

Comment: @JakobMulvadNielsen the error message explicitly informs you about unsafe: "use of mutable static requires unsafe function or block". You are going to have a *very bad time* using Rust if you don't read compiler error messages.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> error[E0133]: use of mutable static requires unsafe function or block
> ```

In general, accessing mutable global variables is *unsafe*, which means that you can only do it in an `unsafe` block. With mutable global variables, it's easy to accidentally create dangling references (think of a reference to an item of a global mutable `Vec`), data races (if you have multiple threads – Rust doesn't care that you don't actually use threads) or otherwise invoke [undefined behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html).

Global variables are usually not the best solution to a problem because it makes your software less flexible and less reusable. Instead, consider passing the state explicitly (by reference, so you don't need to copy it) to the functions that need to operate on it. This lets the calling code work with multiple independent states.

---

Here's an example of allocating unique state and modifying that:

```
type State = i32;

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn new() -> *mut State {
    Box::into_raw(Box::new(0))
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn free(state: *mut State) {
    unsafe { Box::from_raw(state) };
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn add(state: *mut State) {
    unsafe { *state += 1 };
}

#[no_mangle]
pub extern fn get(state: *mut State) -> i32 {
    unsafe { *state }
}
```

```
const fs = require('fs-extra');

fs.readFile(__dirname + '/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/state.wasm')
  .then(bytes => WebAssembly.instantiate(bytes))
  .then(({ module, instance }) => {
    const { new: newFn, free, get, add } = instance.exports;

    const state1 = newFn();
    const state2 = newFn();

    add(state1);
    add(state2);
    add(state1);

    console.log(get(state1));
    console.log(get(state2));

    free(state1);
    free(state2);
});
```

```
2
1
```

*Note* — This currently **needs** to be compiled in release mode to work. Debugging mode has some issues at the moment.

Admittedly, this is not *less* unsafe because you're passing raw pointers around, but it makes it clearer in the calling code that there is some mutable state being manipulated. Also note that it is now the responsibility of the *caller* to ensure that the state pointer is being handled correctly.

Comment: Check out my [Rust FFI Omnibus](http://jakegoulding.com/rust-ffi-omnibus/objects/) which discusses some ways of wrapping this type of FFI in some nicer constructs.